# Show that if $S$ is a vertex cut of cardinality $\kappa (G)$, then $G-S$ has at most $t$ components

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G$ be a non-complete graph of order $n$ and connectivity $k$ such that for every $v\in V(G)$, $deg(v) \geq \frac{n+kt-t}{t+1}$ for some $t \geq 2$. Show that if $S$ is a vertex cut of cardinality $\kappa (G)$, then $G-S$ has at most $t$ components

For this problem, I didn't get very far

Since $G$ be a non-complete graph of order $n$ and connectivity $k$, $|S| \geq k$. I tried to prove this by induction. So

Base : $t=2$. Show that for every $v\in V(G)$, $deg(v) \geq \frac{n+2k-2}{3}$, $G-S$ has at most $2$ components.

However, I can't see how the degree of $V$ can help me complete the base, left alone the inductive step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: do not use induction.

1. Assume that $G-S$ has more than $t$ components.
2. Use the pigeon hole principle to find a component $C$ of $G-S$ that has a small number of vertices.
3. Draw a conclusion about the degree of the vertices in $C$.
4. Then draw a conclusion about the degree of those vertices in $G$.
5. Reach a contradiction with the degree assumption of the problem.

Ad 2.: $G-S$ has $n-k$ vertices. If it has more than $t$ components, it has at least $t+1$ components. Then the pigeon hole principle says there is at least one component with at most $\frac{n-k}{t+1}$ vertices (if every component would have more than $\frac{n-k}{t+1}$ vertices then $G-S$ would have more then $(t+1)\frac{n-k}{t+1}=n-k$ vertices).

Comment: Can you give me a little more detail about how to use pigeon hole principle to find the component of $G-S$ please?

Comment: Done. But I want to learn too: how should I have given that hint without giving it all away?

Comment: I know that $G$ is a regular graph, and $G$ is $k$ connected, so every vertex in $G-S$ will have degree at least $\frac {n-k-t}{t+1}$. I can't see how this related to the component. I know it's related, but just couldn't see that.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this comment. Why is $G$ suddenly regular? And are you reacting to my question or are you having problems with another item. Please clarify.

Comment: oh, sorry, I misunderstood about the degree of $v$. I confused that they are the same, that why I said something about regular graph. I'm still thinking about pigeon hole. I haven't use this principle for 5 years. I guess I should start by assuming the contrary that $g-S$ has more than $t$ component, . Then pick the smallest component, and show that the degree of a vertex in that component, contradict the assumption about the degree. This is where I'm stuck

Comment: Explained item 2 even more. This is the best I can do.